# How to use d3.js on c3.js chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, c3.js

When generating a chart using **c3.js**, is it correct to say that you pass the generate method a configuration object as an argument?

If so, how would I be able to look at the actual chart object that was generated to see what I can **alter using d3.js**?